# Using perl to replace a string with contents from file found in an array

Tags: bash, perl

```
for i in "${arrOfFiles[@]}"; do
   # OUTPUT_PATH=some dynamic naming file created earlier
   perl -pe 's/%REPLACE ME%/`cat $i`/ge' -i "$OUTPUT_PATH"`
done
```

My script hangs up here and never finishes. using `cat $i` reveals the correct contents of the file from the array so $i is working. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use the `e` flag for perl's `s///` operator. `-e` evaluates the right side of the substitution as perl code; you don't want to evaluate the contents of `cat $i` as perl code, you want it treated as literal text to replace.  Since you're using single-quotes in the bash command line, the `cat $i` text gets passed literally to perl and *evaluated as an expression*: which means perl runs a subshell for `cat` and the contents (in perl's mind) of `$i` - which is not a **perl** variable at all.  Without `use strict`, it's entirely legal to have an undeclared variable, so perl doesn't complain when you tell it open a subshell that calls `cat` with no arguments.  `cat` with no arguments of course just waits for stdin .. which is why you see the script "hang".   You're essentially calling this:

```
perl -e '`cat $i`;'
```

Your error is readily apparent if you add `use strict` to your perl code:

```
perl -e 'use strict; `cat $i`;'
```

Your code block should be this:

```
for i in "${arrOfFiles[@]}"; do
    perl -pi -e "s/%REPLACE ME%/`cat $i`/g;" "$OUTPUT_PATH"
done
```

Note, however, that this will always operate on the file named in `$OUTPUT_PATH`, which means that the `%REPLACE ME%` text inside it will get replaced by the contents of the first file in your file array, and then none of the rest of the files will replace anything.  It's unclear as to what exactly you're trying to do here.  With the `-pi` flags to perl, you're telling it to in-line edit any/all of the files given on the command line, which is currently only `$OUTPUT_PATH`.

It's also probably a generally bad way to do string substitution - there are probably any number of characters in the contents of each `$i` file that could totally explode your perl command line. A single `/` character will be enough to cause a perl syntax error, and there are probably sequences that would run arbitrary code via injection.  You've been warned.

Comment: This works and the file is injected. The file in question is a python script however and when the file is inject, some indents are lost and the python script will not execute. What do you think would solve this issue?

Comment: It's tough to say without seeing an example.  It might be better to ask a new question with your updated code and some clarification of how you're expecting to loop even though you only ever replace text in `$OUTPUT_PATH`